# How do I add a custom view on click of a button Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, custom-view

I am working on fragments and I need to show a custom layout on click of a button that contains a list view. This custom layout should be shown below that button.
Can anyone please suggest something for this.I have gone through almost all the links available for xamarin. We can do this in android using SetCustonView method but have no idea how to show it in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, there's a couple of things you can do:

1) You can put your ListView under your button but set its "Visibility" property to "Visibility.Gone." When the button is pressed you can set the Visibility prop to "Visibility.Visible."

```
View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton).Click += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
                {
                    View.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.MyListView).Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
                };
```

2) Another option is to put your ListView in a Fragment. When your button is clicked, you run a FragmentTransaction to add the Fragment to your View.

```
var fragTransaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, myFrag, "current_frag");
fragTransaction.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a better solution to achieve the above expection by using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/popup_menus/)
below is the code that I implemented

```
var buttonClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(Activity, Resource.Id.button);
        menu.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.reports_nav_menu,                     menu.Menu);
        buttonClick .Click += (s, arg) => {
            menu.Show();
        };
        menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) => {
            DisplayMenuOptionsOnClick(s1, arg1);
        };

private void DisplayMenuOptionsOnClick(Object s1,PopupMenu.MenuItemClickEventArgs arg1) {
        switch (arg1.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString()) {
            case "Item 1":
                // Do Something
                break;
            case "Item 2":
                // Do Something
                break;
            case "Item 3":
                // Do Something
                break;
            
        }
        
    }
```

In your Resources -> create folder as 'menu'(if it is not there)
inside menu add xml file and add following code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:id="@+id/item_one"
      android:title="Item One"/>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/item_two"
      android:title="Item Two"/>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/item_three"
      android:title="Item Three"/>

</menu>
```

comment below for more clarification.